# Axios Post Data Not sending in the API

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm a newbie i wanted to display the data the being inputted in form data to post in api. However whenever i click the button it getting the data but in the log of webservice in api it didn't receive the data inserted:

Here is my code for getting the api:

dev.js

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
    NODE_ENV: '"development"',
    BASE_API: '"api(link)?method=auth"'
})
```

Login.vue

```
  methods: {
    onbuttonClicked() {
      this.loading = true
      this.$store
        .dispatch('Login', this.data)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Success');
          this.loading = false
          this.$router.push({ path: this.redirect || '/' })

        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log('Unsuccessful');
          this.loading = false 
        })
    }
  }
```

login.js

```
import request from '@/utils/request'

export function login (username, password) {
console.log("LOGIN username : " + username);
console.log("LOGIN password : " + password);
  return request({
    url: '/login',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      username: username,
      password: password
    }
  })
}
```

user-data.js

```
    Login({ commit }, userInfo) {
        const username = userInfo.username.trim()

        console.log("USER.JS username: " + username);
        console.log("USER.JS password: " + userInfo.password);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            login(username, userInfo.password)
                .then(resp => {
                    const data = resp.data.data
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("USER.JS RESPONSE: " + resp.data.status);
                    console.log("USER.JS RESPONSE: " + resp.data.message);

                    setToken(data.token)
                    commit('SET_TOKEN', data.token)

                    resolve()
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    reject(error)
                })
        })
    }
```

[Result in Printing the data in console log in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohWSg.png)

[Result in WEBSERVICE log the data inputted is not added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXDgk.png)

Comment: Can you show the code from your server?

Comment: sorry server? u mean api server? jsorry

Comment: Yes, the code that handles the request from client.

Comment: I think the server code is okay, because when i try the different ways in method post using the axios.post().the data that i inserted is printing in the api log server. It is running okay. but in this code it is calling the api already but not appearing

Comment: I already solve. Thank youu